# C++: How to set loop variables and conditions for the end of the loop

Tags: c++

Excuse me, I'm having trouble learning C++. Our teacher said in class that in C++ the best way to indicate the end of the loop is `!=`, not `<=`, but I don't understand why. I just encountered the following problem, can someone help me?

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "He123llo"; int count = 0;
    for (string::size_type index = 0; s[index] != '\0'; ++index) {   //（*）
        char ch = s[index];
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}

int another() {
    string s = "He123l4l5o";
    string new1;
    for (string::size_type index = 0; index != s.size(); ++index) {   //（*）
        char ch = s[index];
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
            new1 += ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. What's wrong with changing the statement in (*) to `for (int index=0;index!=s.size();++index)`?
2. What is the problem if the statement in (*) is modified to `for (string::size_type index=0;index<=s.size();++index)`?
3. Can the statement in (*) be modified to `for (string::size_type index=0;s[index]!=’\0’;++index)`?
4. In the above code, the length of the string has not changed. Now: In `another()` function, please re-answer questions 2 and 3.

Comment: (1),(2) is correct, (3) is incorrect because end of a std::string which isn't '\0'  , (4) same above

Comment: In `another()`.  For modern c++, preferred use would be `for (const auto ch : s)` or `for (const auto& ch : s)`.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like arrays, strings are 0-indexed, meaning the valid character indexes are `0` to `size-1`.

If you use `s[index] != '\0'` or  `index <= s.size()`, accessing the character at index `s.size()` is *undefined behavior* prior to C++11, and in C++11 and later it accesses the string's null terminator (technically, C++ strings are not null-terminated, but they include a null terminator for compatibility with C).

Using `index != s.size()` or `index < s.size()` is safe in all C++ versions.